# Finding all physically connected objects with X,Y values contained in a list

Tags: c#, xna

I have a list of objects, each of which has the following properties

```
int X 
int Y
bool deletable
enum color
```

The objects are drawn to the screen in a grid pattern according to their X and Y values. A grid may look like this, where Y represents a yellow object and B a blue one.

```
YYYBBYYY
BBYYYYBB
```

When for example, a new yellow object collides with a yellow object on the grid, I'd like to find all of the connected objects and set their deletable property to true. Essentially, I need to work backwards from the last element added to the list and work out the chain of physically touching objects.

What I'm looking for is some idea as to how to go forward. I can find all of the first neighbours and set them to deletable, but beyond that it's murky. Do I cycle through the list a second time, finding the matching neighbours of everything that has deletable set to true? Do I repeat this a number of times to find everything?

I feel like there's a simpler solution that I'm blind to.

Answer (score 0):

While terse, Brian's answer is correct.  In this case, you would replace setting the color and checking the color (when determining whether it has already been done) to setting the deletable property and checking the deletable property.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating. That seems like something I should have been able to Google myself. What search terms would you have used in my position?

Comment: Couldn't tell you.  Assuming one doesn't already know the name "flood fill", I'm having a hard time finding an answer to the question on Google.

Comment: @David I searched for `bucket fill algorithm` thinking of the bucket tool in Paint